# What is the MIME type when using the HTML capture attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

For mobile browsers, you can open the camera to capture a photo like this:

```
<input type="file" id="imageFile" capture="user" accept="image/*">
```

What is the MIME type of the captured file, how do I find out (jpg, png, gif, ...)?

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture
- https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/#dom-htmlinputelement-capture

Comment: I would assume it's device/environment-specific, but you can find out by trying it and checking the file.

Comment: Good question. If I read the specs right, I think it's up to the browser to decide how to create the input of the specified category -- just like the `*` in the `accept` indicates. Have you already tried what happens when you use something specific like `accept="image/png"`?

Comment: w3 says "If the accept attribute's value is set to a MIME type that has no associated capture control type, the user agent MUST act as if there was no capture attribute." So, yeah, it's dependent on the capture device. It's likely going to be jpg, though. And your page shouldn't care what kind of format the image is in so long as the browser understands the format.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited android experiments, the browser just seems to create a file with an extension
e.g.

```
{name: '121221424284772878477248.jpeg', type = 'images/jpeg', ... }
```